# Does not support nested virtualization on this host

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, nested-virtualization

I have installed EVE-ng VM to VMWare Workstation 15.5. During the power ON it popups an Error mentioning:

> “VMware Workstation does not support nested virtualization on this host.”

After that, I disabled Hyper-V, Virtual machine platform and Windows Hypervisor platform. But still, I am facing the same issue. Please help me with this. It would be a great help.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Uninstall VMware 15.5, Ensure Hyper-V and associated components are off.  Restart.  Install VMware Workstation 16.2 and test.

Comment: Post a screenshot of `msinfo32` by editing your question.  Be sure to include all relevant information from the image. VMWare has supported being installed on hosts with Hyper-V for awhile now. In particular we are looking for the phrase, " A hypervisor has been detected. " in the output of msinfo32

Comment: Hi John ...I tried with 16.2 Version, But no luck,

Comment: HI Ramhound, I have attached msinfo32 details.